# Android memory problem

Tags: java, android, memory-management, file-upload, memory-leaks

Hi
I have to upload different files (Images, Videos and Audio). But the system is crashing due to low memory.
I have a lot of controls and each have different listeners. Please point me the best way i need to go so that i use the memory efficiently.
When i checked using DDMS eclipse, the memory is creeping from screen to screen. And when i upload once that memory is not removing. I have stored every files in sdcard and at the time of upload this using

```
FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File (path/filename) ,Fileformat);
```

I think the memory used here are also unallocated. I have declared this in a local function scope hoping the GC will manage this when the scope is gone. But it is not happening for me.
Please help me, What i need to do here? Is there any way to explicitly call GC on some objects?  How to remove object data object? From DDMS eclipse, i got it is data object which is using main portion of my memory. Which all come under this?
Thanks

Comment: What are you doing to read the file and upload it?

Comment: Thanks @Macarse for considering my question, Me using httpclient and httppost packages here. Posting using HttpPost

Comment: So you are reading the whole file to memory and then sending? I guess that's the issue.

Comment: @Macarse: ho ho so what i need to do to save memory?

Comment: Do not read everything to memory before start sending.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity` to create a http post entity?  The content of this http entity will be streamed from the given file automatically with streamlined memory and cpu consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try too implement streaming wherever you can. You can also tip the garbage collector by `null`ing objects you don't need any more, and/or calling `System.gc()`